# Immutable priority queue in Guava

Tags: java, performance, guava, immutability

I try make immutable priority queue using Guava library. As queue 'backend' I used ImmutableSortedMultiset. But I have a problem with performance - operation push and pop are very slow. What is the best way to add and remove single item from sorted immutable collection? 
Thanks!

This is my code:

```java
public class ImmutablePriorityQueue<T extends Comparable<T>> implements PriorityQueue<T> {

    private final ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> multiset;

    private ImmutablePriorityQueue() {
        this(ImmutableSortedMultiset.<T>of());
    }

    private ImmutablePriorityQueue(ImmutableSortedMultiset<T> multiset) {
        this.multiset = multiset;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> PriorityQueue<T> createEmpty() {
        return new ImmutablePriorityQueue<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new EmptyCollectionException();
        return multiset.firstEntry().getElement();
    }

    @Override
    public PriorityQueue<T> push(T element) {
        ImmutableSortedMultiset.Builder<T> builder = multiset.naturalOrder();
        return new ImmutablePriorityQueue<T>(builder.add(element).addAll(multiset.asList()).build());
    }

    @Override
    public PriorityQueue<T> pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new EmptyCollectionException();
        ImmutableSortedMultiset.Builder<T> builder = multiset.naturalOrder();
        return new ImmutablePriorityQueue<T>(builder.addAll(multiset.asList().subList(1, size())).build());
    }

    @Override
    public PriorityQueue<T> clear() {
        return new ImmutablePriorityQueue<T>();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return multiset.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return multiset.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of the pop() method? It doesn't even return the element that has been popped? And why would there be a push() and a pop() method in an *immutable* queue? Adn why use a multiset to implement a queue? I think you're on a wrong road. What do you want to achieve with this queue?

Comment: @JBNizet I suppose the OP is using a sorted multiset because it needs to be sorted and the same element can be in the set multiple times. I agree with your other points.

Comment: I want immutable object - priority queue. That's reason why I have implemented methods push and pop. This methods are typical for priority queue. How I can add single element to sorted immutable collection? What is the best way? Method pop removed first (with hightest priority) element from priority queue.

Comment: immutable means: which doesn't change. Pushing and popping are changes. There is a contradiction here. What do you want to do with an immutable queue?

Comment: Yes, thats is right - I known. Therefore return type is new collection. I don't change object. What is the other way? Contructor with two parameters - old data and new element? Or builder? But If I use builder then is AddAll and Add method is slowly becouse collection are will sorted for each item.

Comment: As I said, pop() should return what has been popped, otherwise the method is useless. You still haven't explained why you want an immutable queue. A queue is typically something that you *want* to be mutable, because it is used to push and pop constantly.

Comment: I want immutable priority queue for mainly two reasons. For my algorithm is better immutable object but not necessary (thread safe, ...). And other reason is chalenge for me - I try implemented all class like immutable objects.

Comment: None of the Guava types are going to be able to represent this type of data structure efficiently.  You'll have to roll your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks more like a "CopyOnWrite" data structure, at least this is how it's called in Java. You might want to have a look at the implementation of `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, but still it is different in that it does not returns a copy of an object, but locks the internal state and creates a copy of it.

Immutable objects in Guava normally prohibit modifications made to the object, i.e. an excerpt from the `ImmutableList`:

```
@Deprecated
@Override
public final E set(int index, E element) {
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

Now, concerning the performance of `pop()` operation, `asList()` would create an interim array to store elements, so creating a copy this way would presumably have a smaller overhead:

```
TreeMultiset<String> original = TreeMultiset.create(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "a", "c", "b", "d"));
System.out.println("original: " + original);

SortedMultiset<String> tail = ImmutableSortedMultiset.copyOfSorted(original.tailMultiset(original.firstEntry().getElement(), BoundType.OPEN));
System.out.println("tail: " + tail);
```

The idea is to take the first entry and query for a range with it being a left open bound (meaning "excluding"). This prints:

```
original: [a x 2, b x 2, c, d]
tail: [b x 2, c, d]
```

You might also need to return a pair of the newly created collection and of an element which was popped for not losing an element which was popped. This is just an idea, I am not sure if this approach is used anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tail I cannot use because it's not possible if I have duplicate values in collection. CopySorted is okay but how I can faster add or remove single item?

Comment: I've update the answer to illustrate the `tail()` application. I am not sure I understand how you want to remove a single item. It's impossible to remove an item from an immutable Guava collection. You can remove an item from a regular collection, i.e. `TreeMultiset` with `remove()` or you could return a modified copy of an immutable object which is what you are doing.